# One hot three neutrals in a box: help resolve electrical wiring mystery

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

I had to remove an outlet in a room and I traced the wire back to this junction box that houses a light switch. I disconnected all splices (solder + tape) in the box (foolishly without marking the wires) and cut the metal cable leading to the outlet I needed to remove with a high leverage cutter.

Now, I'm trying to figure out what's going on in this box. I've identified the hot and temporarily put a connector on it to extend it. I've identified the hot that goes to the light. I figured that of the remaining 3 wires I would have 1 hot that used to go outlet and 2 neutrals. However, here's what I'm finding out that I'm yet to figure out:

1. The light turns out when I touch the light wire to the hot (even though all other wires are disconnected). The only way I have of explaining this is that the home run goes to the light first and from there two conductors to the box.
2. All three other wires short circuit when I touch hot to them. The only way I have of explaining this is when I cut the wire with the high leverage cutter, I short circuited it and it's still sitting there in the wall with the hot touching the neutral.

Am I right in my assessments or is there a better explanation?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we get a better photo of the inside of the box? The existing one is terribly shadowed, sadly :/

Comment: Which nation are you in?

Comment: With the terminal blocks not wire nuts I would guess UK. What voltage may be a better question.

Comment: Added new picture with a flash.
Country: US
Voltage: 120V
House built: 1940

Comment: I can't answer your question but I will say: 1) don't deliberately short circuit the wiring. You can damage the wire, and it is tempting fate with the fire gods. Use a multimeter. 2) the color of the wire is an indication of it's purpose but doesn't guarantee it. If you think something is weird you should not assume anything.

Comment: So when is the light *on* ?  If the light switch was in that box, you removed said switch, but the light is lit, then there is a dangerous situation, i.e. hot feed direct to the  light fixture.

Comment: Carl, the light is on when I touch "hot" to "light" as labeled in the first picture.
Henry, your "don't short" comment is duly noted. Those shorts were actually inadvertent.